# React class component: defining value inside vs outside render function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation in my React Native app, and I'm using the [useNavigation hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/). In a functional component you'd import the hook and define its output to a variable like this:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Screen1(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (...);
}
```

but I use class components in my app.

**What I Want To Know:** If I want to do the equivalent ^^ in a class component, what's the difference between defining `navigation` inside vs outside the render method?

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

class Screen1 extends Component {
  const navigation1 = useNavigation(); // OPTION 1
  render() {
    const navigation2 = useNavigation(); // OPTION 2
    return(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are only [accessible inside functional components](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions), so the code snippet using hooks in the class is invalid. You cannot use `useNavigation` hook to access navigation prop in the class component. Instead, you have to access the `navigation` prop from the props object present on `this` object of the class component using `this.props.navigation`. So, your class component will look something like this:

```js
class Screen1 extends Component {
  navigation1 = this.props.navigation; // OPTION 1
  render() {
    const navigation2 = this.props.navigation; // OPTION 2
    return(...);
  }
}
```

Notice, with OPTION 1, I am not using `const` since that is not valid in class component.But you can use `let` or `const` inside a method of the class though like it is being used in OPTION 2.

The main difference which I can think is that of where it can be accessed. `navigation1` has broader scope than `navigation2`. `navigation1` can be used inside `render` but `navigation2` cannot used be outside render in the wider class body.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I want to use the hook is that I need it in some components that are part of a nested navigator and so don't have the navigation prop. Specifically, I'm following this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/   Do you know how I can get the navigation option in a components where I don't have this.props.navigation?